# Entity Framework returning old data with disposable context

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

This is the first time I'm seeing this problem.

Consider my repository method :

```
public async Task<List<Code>> GetAllByType(string type)
{
    using (var ctx = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return await ctx.Codes.Where(code => code.Type.Equals(type)).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

This is the issue I've stumbled upon while trying to create an observable collection for my view that is created from the result of the method above. As so :

```
Types = new ObservableCollection<Code>(await CodeRepository.GetAllByType("TestType"));
```

Even though I'm using a disposable context, every time I make a query, the repository returns old data. I've manually edited some of the entries with `"TestType"` as their column value, it's still the unchanged old data. I've added 3 new entries, those are ***not found***.

Yes, *I do have entries in the database*. Database is non-case-sensitive, I've tried all combinations, whatever I do - Entity Framework context is still returning old data.

Anyone had this issue before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Manually edited"? What does that mean?

Comment: I opened the SQL table, and edited the column entry manually.

Comment: for starter, you can break down the problem to see where it doesn't work properly. you have several possible cases: 1.linq query fails, 2. async fails, 3. observablecollection fails 4. somewhere else fails

Comment: Where did you do this? You are probably editing the wrong database.

Comment: I'm the stupidest person alive. Thanks, was using wrong database. I think it's time to be done with work for now, 14 hours is more than enough. Can you please respond with Answer for people to check their connection strings and database for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably editing the wrong database. Please double-check your connection string and make sure that you are editing the one that your application actually connects to.

Answer (score 2):

This is not your case, but EF can return old datas if the Context is declared like a static property. For example :

```
public MyController : Controller {
    public static DatabaseContext Db = new DatabaseContext();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will note for the future reference.